# What does the '\' at the end of a #define statement mean?

Tags: c++

I saw this code:

```
#define REPEAT(statement) \
{ \
    while((count & ~0x7) && ((x+8) < width)) \
        UNROLL8( statement; count--; x++; ); \
    \
    while((count > 0) && (x < width)) \
    { \
        statement; \
        count--; \
        x++; \
    } \
}
```

What is the `\` for here?

Comment: it means the `#define` is extended to more than one line

Comment: It's a line continuation character.

Comment: Please don't answer and upvote this duplicate question which lacks research effort. Please close it as a duplicate instead.

Comment: @STLDeveloper Why do you think so? The syntax is well explained there ...

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ - The OP doesn't know isn't asking how to make a multi-line preprocessor directive. He's seen something that he doesn't understand is asking assistance in identifying it.  Those are not the same thing.

Comment: @STLDeveloper It's not the point about the literal question text for marking something as a duplicate, but that there's an appropriate answer for the OP's problems.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I disagree.  In this case the OP would have to know the answer what he's looking at in order to find that answer.  The reason for that is because that question is not the OP's question.  BTW, are you often a troll?

Comment: @STLDeveloper You may disagree of course! Until you have enough rep to participate in [close/repoen voting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges), this might turn out to be pretty irrelevant.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - Now there's something we can agree upon!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In macro definition, `\` means *continuation*.

The definition of a macro should be on ONE line, i.e without any break. Since in your definition, the macro definition is so big that it cannot conveniently accommodate on the same line without destroying the readability. So `\` is used to indicate to the preprocessor the definition **continues** to the next line so that the program's readability is maintained.

Note that `\` must be followed by a newline. Make sure that there is **no** space after `\`.

Comment: It means continuation outside of a macro too, it's just that it usually doesn't matter anywhere else.

Answer (score 4):

The definition of a macro only includes a logical single line. The `\` at the end of each line of the macro definition is used to allow the macro definition to be split into multiple physical source lines (presumably for readability reasons).

This works because a `\` followed by a new-line is deleted during phase two of translation, but the preprocessor is run later, in phase four. `[lex.phases]/2`:

> Each instance of a backslash character (\) immediately followed by a new-line character is deleted, splicing physical source lines to form logical source lines.

Answer (score 1):

those are line continuations necessary to interpret the whole `#define` thing as one line, as required by the preprocessor syntax. this way it's just more readable.

Answer (score 1):

It means that the macro text is continued after the actual line breaks you have.

`#define` reads its contents from one contigious line. The `\` character just *'escapes'* (i.e. skips) the following line break.